# Does $f'''$ exist or not?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Does there exist  a  function  $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  such  that  the  derivatives  $f' , f''$  exist  but  not $f'''$?

I  thinks this exists.  Take  $f(x) = |x|^3$ . Then $f'$ and $f''$ exist everywhere, but $f'''$  does not exist at $0$. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Another simple example would be $x^{\frac{7}{3}}$.

Comment: sir  i think  u  forgot to put Mod   it  should   be  put  $f(x)  =|x^{7/3}|$

Comment: @jasmine It works out either way.  Since $x\mapsto x^3:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is bijective, $f(x)=(x^7)^\frac13$ is well-defined.

Answer (score 3):

In fact there exists a twice continuously differentiable function $f$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $f'''(x)$ exists nowhere. Proof: Let $W$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb R$ that is nowhere differentiable (Weierstrass). Then set

$$f(y)=\int_0^y\int_0^x W(t)\,dt.$$

Then $f''(y)=W(y)$ everywhere. But since $W$ is not differentiable anywhere, $f'''(y)$ exists nowhere.